# root can't see HISTTIMEFORMAT in user's bash_history

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command, root

I have a little question about log date in bash_history for each users.
Last time I set in /etc/skel/.bashrc for each new user:

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "
```

All things seems to be fine if we check our bash_history with `history` command in shell. But only if we are loged a current user.
My problem is when I want to check user's .bash_history file as root user.
So I use e.g. less command on /home/new_user/.bash_history file (as root user!) and I see this:

```
#1537351240
cd ..
#1537351241
vim
#1537357293
ls -al /mnt
#1537357313
htop
```

I can't see right date format near user's commands and I don't know what's means: `#1537357313` ?
I just would like to takie this normal output format:

```
3  28/09/18 15:31:50 cd ..
4  28/09/18 15:31:52 vim
5  28/09/18 15:31:57 ls -al /mnt
6  28/09/18 15:32:10 htop
```

(dates in above are example)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it will be closed on the StackOverflow, but it would be likely ontopic on the https://unix.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 1):

*I don't know what's means: #1537357313 ?*

It's the unix timestamp:

```
date -d @1537357313
Wed, Sep 19, 2018  1:41:53 PM
```

So you can process this file with `awk`:

```
awk '/^#/{t=strftime("%d/%m/%y %T",substr($1,2));next}t{print ++i,t,$0}' file
1 19/09/18 12:00:40 cd ..
2 19/09/18 12:00:41 vim
3 19/09/18 13:41:33 ls -al /mnt
4 19/09/18 13:41:53 htop
```

Comment: ok, it's some idea for build some script to "convert" file etc. but can I see histtimeformat as root user without converting file? It's not a big problem ;) but I'm curious how to change it (in global space) permanently or maybe exist some another solve?